# SQL select query memory issues

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got this server setting a live traffic log DB that holds a big stats table. Now I need to create a smaller table from it, let's say 30 days back.

This server also has a slave server that copies the data and is 5 sec behind the master.
I created this slave in order to reduce server process for selecting queries so it only works with insert/update for the traffic log.

Now I need to copy the last day to the smaller table, and still not to use the "real" DB,
so I need to select from the slave and insert to the real smaller table. (The slave only allows read operations).

I am working with PHP and I can't solve this with one query using two different databases at one query... If it's possible, please let me know how?

When using two queries I need to hold the last day as a PHP MySQL object. For 300K-650K of rows, it's starting to be a cache memory problem. I would use a partial select by ID(by setting the ids at the where term) chunks but I don't have an auto increment id field and there's no id for the rows (when storing traffic data id would take a lot of space).

So I am trying this idea and I would like to get a second opinion.

If I will take the last day at once (300K rows) it will overload the PHP memory.
I can use limit chunks, or a new idea: selecting one column at a time and copying this one to the new real table. But I don't know if the second method is possible. Does insert looks at the first open space at a column level or row level? 
the main idea is reducing the size of the select.. so is it possible to build a select by columns and then insert them as columns at mysql?

Comment: Why are you talking about your tables as though they are people? 0_0

Comment: @JackManey: Because English is not Amir's native language and the direct transliteration of some languages would use 'him' or 'her' in place of a neutral 'it'.

Answer (score 0):

If this is simply a memory problem in PHP you could try using PDO and fetching 1 result row at a time instead of a all at the same time.

From [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) for PDO:

```
<?php
function getFruit($conn) {
    $sql = 'SELECT name, color, calories FROM fruit ORDER BY name';
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        print $row['name'] . "\t";
        print $row['color'] . "\t";
        print $row['calories'] . "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: well here is where php start to be weird.. i took your advice and started to  use chunks for the data. i used a loop for advancing a limit in 2000 rows jumps. but what was interesting is when i started to use php memory usage and memory peak functions  i found out that the reason the chunks method doesn't work in large scales and looping is because setting a new value to a var doesn't release the memory of what was before the new setting.. so you must use unset or null in order to keep your memory at php,

Answer (score 0):

well here is where php start to be weird.. i took your advice and started to use chunks for the data. i used a loop for advancing a limit in 2000 rows jumps. but what was interesting is when i started to use php memory usage and memory peak functions i found out that the reason the chunks method doesn't work in large scales and looping is because setting a new value to a var doesn't release the memory of what was before the new setting.. so you must use unset or null in order to keep your memory at php, –